# Eigen::NullaryExpr input to operator

Tags: c++, operators, eigen

can someone please help me with the understanding of the Eigen::NullaryExpr().

I have a functor with the operator() inside as

```
template<typename Scalar>
  struct scalar_op
    template<typename Index>
    inline const Scalar operator()(Index, Index = 0,bool flag=true) const 
    { 
        if(flag) 
          .....
        else 
          .....
    }
 }
```

now I am using the operator as

```
scalar_op<Scalar> _f1;
Matrix<Scalar,Dynamic,-1> samples(int nn)
{    
   return Matrix<Scalar,Dynamic,-1>::NullaryExpr(nn,1,true,_f1);
}
```

I get a error message like :

error C2780: 'const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp Eigen::DenseBase::NullaryExpr(const CustomNullaryOp &)' : expects 1 arguments - 4 provided

without the argument "bool flag=true" i.e.

```
inline const Scalar operator()(Index, Index = 0) const
```

and the modification:

```
return Matrix<Scalar,Dynamic,-1>::NullaryExpr(nn,1,_f1);
```

my code compiles and works okay(in a sense that I cannot use a conditional statement within operator() any more).

My lack of understanding the NullaryExpr() is causing this error. My question is how do I pass an argument "flag" into the operator () so that I can use it inside it.

It would be very kind if someone explains what my error is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the `flag` as a member of your functor that you initialize through its constructor, for instance:

```
template<typename Scalar> struct scalar_op {
  bool m_flag;
  explicit scalar_op(bool flag=true) : m_flag(flag) {}
  template<typename Index>
  inline const Scalar operator()(Index, Index = 0) const 
  { 
    if(m_flag) 
      .....
    else 
      .....
  }
};
```

and call it this way:

```
VectorXd::NullaryExpr(n, scalar_op<double>(false));
```